# jdk_1.7.0_40 installation on SUSE

Tags: unix, java-7, rpm

I downloaded the jdk_7u40-linux-x64.rpm, and then ran the rpm -ivh jdk_7u40-linux-x64.rpm.
How to know that this installation was successful?, Also when i ran java -version, it showed me earlier version.

Then i downloaded the jdk.**_*_*.tar.gz, and followed the http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Installing_Java#Updating_Oracle_Java, but still java version is unchanged, can anybody please tell me what i am missing here or are there any steps which i dont know about, thanks in advance.

Thanks and Regards,

Rohit

Thanks, got it solved,You can do this with sudo update-alternatives

Comment: Do you have the environment variable JAVA_HOME defined?

Comment: yes, but its pointing to previous installation